# Data to explode between two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My current dataframe looks as below:

```
existing_data = {'STORE_ID': ['1234','5678','9876','3456','6789'],
        'FULFILLMENT_TYPE': ['DELIVERY','DRIVE','DELIVERY','DRIVE','DELIVERY'], 
        'FORECAST_DATE':['2020-08-01','2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05'],
        'DAY_OF_WEEK':['SATURDAY','SUNDAY','MONDAY','TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY'],
        'START_HOUR':[8,8,6,7,9],
        'END_HOUR':[19,19,18,19,17]}

existing = pd.DataFrame(data=existing_data)
```

I would need the data to be exploded between the start and end hour such that each hour is a different row like below:

```
needed_data = {'STORE_ID': ['1234','1234','1234','1234','1234'],
        'FULFILLMENT_TYPE': ['DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY'], 
        'FORECAST_DATE':['2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-08-01','2020-08-01'],
        'DAY_OF_WEEK': ['SATURDAY','SATURDAY','SATURDAY','SATURDAY','SATURDAY'],
        'HOUR':[8,9,10,11,12]}

required = pd.DataFrame(data=needed_data)
```

Not sure how to achieve this ..I know it should be with explode() but unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If small DataFrame or performance is not important use `range` per both columns with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
existing['HOUR'] = existing.apply(lambda x: range(x['START_HOUR'], x['END_HOUR']+1), axis=1)
existing = (existing.explode('HOUR')
                    .reset_index(drop=True)
                    .drop(['START_HOUR','END_HOUR'], axis=1))
```

If performance is important use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by subtract both columns and then add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `START_HOUR`:

```
s = existing["END_HOUR"].sub(existing["START_HOUR"]) + 1
df = existing.loc[existing.index.repeat(s)].copy()

add = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df['HOUR'] = df["START_HOUR"].add(add)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop(['START_HOUR','END_HOUR'], axis=1)
```